# Spell Checker in the Search function

Tags: feature-request, search

It's possible to add a spell checker to the search function? 
Something like the Google one... 
(for instance if I write blacd hole in this site I found nothing, while in Google he understand that I want to search for the word black hole).

It's not compelling, but it can be really useful especially for non-english native speakers.

Comment: It's a bit X/Y prob.. um, I mean request. My first impression when reading the title was to add spell checker *when typing* on search box, which I somewhat disagree (many browsers already have this feature), while on the other hand, what you wanted is a smart-prediction on searching, which I think it's a dupe.